# Smartsheet Document Builder

Tags: c#, automation, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I am looking to generate a document using the Smartsheet document builder, through C#.
I have the document mapped in mappings, and data in the rows, now I just need to be able to link the two through my program to automate the creation of our job sheets.

Is this possible? If so, is there documentation of this somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this scenario is supported at this time. If it were supported via API, I'd expect to see it described in the [Smartsheet API docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs) -- but there's no mention of it there.

For what it's worth, there's been some discussion of this topic in the Smartsheet Community Forum -- for example: [Automating document creation](https://community.smartsheet.com/discussion/68152/automating-document-creation). If you haven't done so already, you might consider submitting a [Product Enhancement Request](https://app.smartsheet.com/b/form/739aa75f30ca43a8a22eb53e4da7d409?_ga=2.40282212.778845192.1616684072-2141397834.1616684072) to request API support for this feature.